# multiple sql command

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm trying to execute multiple sql commands, but it gives me "error in your SQL syntax;"

```
Db_Connection dbconn = new Db_Connection();
Connection myconnection = dbconn.Connection();
String sqlString = "SELECT DISTINCT std_id FROM std_crs WHERE crs_id ='222123'; "
     + "SELECT * FROM cplus_grades ;";
Statement myStatement = myconnection.createStatement();

boolean results = myStatement.execute(sqlString);
do {
     if (results) {
          ResultSet rs = myStatement.getResultSet();

          while (rs.next()) {
          }
          rs.close();
     }
     results = myStatement.getMoreResults();
} while(results);

myStatement.close();
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378758(v=sql.110).aspx
check this link .. I'm doing the same thing I guess, right ?

Comment: +1 for showing this feature. Maybe you need to remove the last semicolon in the sql string. The feature may also not be supported by every JDBC driver. What driver and database do you use? Is it a sql server like in your link?

Comment: I'm using phpMyAdmin

Comment: complete wrong two nested sql statements..

Comment: Technically a JDBC statement should only execute one statement at a time. Some drivers allows this, but it is non-standard.

Answer (score 3):

I did a small test with three JDBC drivers:

- MS SQL: works, returns two result sets
- MySQL: fails with a syntax error - that is what you are seeing
- HSQLDB: runs, but returns only one result set.

So I guess it simply depends on the JDBC driver if this technique works. Maybe it works only in MS SQL JDBC.

**UPDATE:**

It also works with Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

please 
1. String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://yourDatabase?allowMultiQueries=true";
this should be your jdbc connection url